# Getting the max value per day in 10 years

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

this is my code, and gets the maximum value for each day in 10 years.

`tmax = weather.set_index(['Date']).resample('D').max().resample('D').max()`
Looks like this:

[image]

But now i want only the maximum value per day no matter the year, so it would be a 365 rows.
Assume that i dont have leap-years and the index is datetime.
Thanks

Comment: IIUC `df.loc[df.groupby(df.index.dt.day).idxmax()]`

Comment: Thanks for the time man :)

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is in the same situation, i found the following solution:

Creates new column with the number of the year

`tmax['dayofyear'] = tmax.index.dayofyear`

Now they are grouped by the number of the day and only the max value is left.

`tmax = tmax.groupby('dayofyear').max()`